# Database schema - Set Limit values in correlation to groups and/or it's members

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database-design, ms-access, relational-theory

Provided there are pre-existing tables (diagram attached below). They each have numerous use-case as far as potentially related attributes. Still, I am at a roadblock following best practices with confidence, trying to add a specific piece of functionality that we can call *Limit* with its respected table and associated attributes, which will have more than just an int value.

**Pre-existing tables (reduced to relevant attributes):**

[image: Pre-Existing Tables Diagram]

**Limit Table:**

[image: Limit Table Diagram]

The problem is, I want to be able to apply a "Limit" value to both, Tasks and Groups, but find it hard to choose between the following approaches I have come up with due to the pros and cons and what could be considered best practice.

**Approach 1:**

[image: ERD Approach 1]

*In the Limit table, add two foreign keys attributes (task_id, group_id) to each tuple (row)*

**Approach 2:**

[image: ERD Approach 2]

*In the Limit table, add one foreign key attribute (taskgroup_id) with a "toggle" attribute (is_group) to each tuple (row)*

**Thoughts:**

Naturally, I think the second can be considered better practice because it reduces the number of NULL values being inserted into the database, and therefore, is more along the lines of a relational database structure.

To make functionality brief, each Task should be assigned a Limit Value, but if no Limit tuple/row is inserted for a Task with a Limit Value, we should refer to the Task’s respected Group for the Limit Value (one Group is linked to all Tasks).

Based on the approaches I have listed, which approach would be better as far as best practice, or is there one you can think of that is better than the two provided?

Please advise if I should elaborate somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither.  TaskLimit, and GroupLimit should be separate tables, or separate columns on the Task and Group tables.

Answer (score 0):

You will be changing limit values, correct?  But not names of groups, etc.

- Overnormalization -- Don't bother names unless there will be (1) millions of references to the name or (2) the name changes frequently.
- If the above changes do not get rid of the many-to-many mapping table(s), then improve the indexes; see [*Many:many mapping*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)
- If there is still a choice between the two ERDs, write out the `SELECTs` that will be needed.  That will probably help you decide between the two schema designs.